# Python code that will find 2 words concatenated made out of specific letters. Letters must be used once only

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

If I have a list of words in the variable words and a list of letters in the variable letters, how can I find all the concatenations of 2 words that can be made up out of the letters in letters. The letters in letters must only be used once each; but you can list the same letter more than once. All letters in letters must be used. I would like to do this in Python.

I have code for finding single words from letters, but how do I change this to find 2 words concatenated instead:

```
letters = ['A', 'E', 'H', 'R', 'T']
words = ['DUMMY', 'EARTH']

[w for w in words if sorted(w) == letters]
```

So given

```
letters = ['A', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'M', 'M', 'R', 'T', 'U', 'Y']
```

I would like to find

```
'DUMMYEARTH'
```

Comment: Why not first calculate all permutations of any two words?

Comment: 'EARTHDUMMY' is also a solution, should the first word always precede?

Comment: How would I first calculate all permutations of any two words?

Comment: words = [(w+w2) for w in af, w2 in af if sorted(zip(w, w2)) == letters] does not work for example

Comment: Please clarify what is the question.

Comment: @Superdooperhero: but `[(w+w2) for w in af, w2 in af if sorted(w+w2) == letters]` should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need this for pairs:

```
from itertools import combinations

words = ['DUMMY', 'EARTH']
letters = ['A', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'M', 'M', 'R', 'T', 'U', 'Y']

[w for w in (''.join(c) for c in combinations(words,2)) 
                               if sorted(w) == letters]
# ['DUMMYEARTH']
```

---

This would work with all combinations:

```
[w for w in (''.join(c) for i in xrange(len(words)+1) 
                      for c in combinations(words,i)) 
                              if sorted(w) == letters]
# ['DUMMYEARTH']
```

Answer (score -1):

concatenate the words with the + operator, then do the check.